# Can I make text badges for Safari App Extension toolbar buttons less ugly?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-app-extension

[Safari App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017319) don’t allow you to change toolbar button images dynamically, but they do let you [add a string to the button as a badge](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/AddingaToolbar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017319-CH9-SW8) by passing a string to the extension handler’s `validationHandler` method:

```
override func validateToolbarItem(in window: SFSafariWindow, validationHandler: @escaping ((Bool, String) -> Void)) {
        // This is called when Safari's state changed in some way that would require the extension's toolbar item to be validated again.
        validationHandler(true, "1")
    }
```

Unfortunately, this badged text doesn’t look great:

[image]

I can’t find anything in the documentation about customising the look of the badged text, but just in case, is there any way to avoid the clipping of what is presumably meant to be a circular badge?

Comment: I think its not possible , safari have a design chart who cannot be altered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the look of the badge text. However, it is now possible to set the button image dynamically, using the toolbar item's [`setImage` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafaritoolbaritem#symbols).

For example, including the following in your `SFSafariExtensionHandler` will change the toolbar item icon to the default user icon when the button is clicked:

```
override func toolbarItemClicked(in window: SFSafariWindow) {
    let image = NSImage(named: NSImageNameUser)
    window.getToolbarItem { $0?.setImage(image) }
}
```

You can provide any `NSImage`, though it should conform to Apple's [guidelines for template images](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ToolbarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH89-SW3).

I don't know why this isn't documented in the Safari App Extension Programming Guide you linked to. I suspect this feature may have been added later and that the Guide is out of date.